# Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts

Tags: typescript

I'm got warning `Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345) Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)`

This my request body:

```
{"A":[{"filter":[{"a":"a"}]},{"group":[{"a":"a"}]}],"B":[{"filter":[{"a":"a"}]},{"group":[{"a":"a"}]}], ...}
```

This is my script :

```
var a = Object.entries(body).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {                                                                    
 acc.filter.push(...value[0].filter);                                                                    
 acc.group.push(...value[1].group);
 return acc;
}, {filter: <any>[], group: <any>[]});
```

The warning come from `...value[0].filter` and `...value[1].group` i'm think because variable type `unknow` on `key` and `value` from `[key, value]`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's use a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) to make sure that the compiler understands that each property of `body` is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) where the first element has a `filter` property and the second element has a `group` property.  (If this isn't true then your `value[0].filter` and `value[1].group` code isn't safe):

```
const body = {
  A: [{ filter: [{ a: "a" }] }, { group: [{ a: "a" }] }],
  B: [{ filter: [{ a: "a" }] }, { group: [{ a: "a" }] }]
} as const;
```

The problem you're running into is this: the compiler sees you calling `array.reduce(callback, initialAccumulator)` where `initialAccumulator` is an object with empty arrays in it, and thinks these arrays must always have no real elements (e.g., `Array<never>`).  When you try to push stuff onto such an array, it complains that the stuff isn't `never`.  You need to use some way to annotate or assert that the accumulator is going to be holding an array of something, as in the following:

```
interface Filter { a: string }; // some type for Filter
interface Group { a: string }; // some type for Group
interface FiltersAndGroups {
  filter: Filter[];
  group: Group[];
}

// manually specify FiltersAndGroups as the accumulator type:     
var a = Object.entries(body).reduce<FiltersAndGroups>(
  (acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc.filter.push(...value[0].filter);
    acc.group.push(...value[1].group);
    return acc;
  },
  { filter: [], group: [] } 
)
```

The `Filter`, `Group` and `FiltersAndGroups` types were chosen to represent the accumulator type, and (as @ShanonJackson [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745339/argument-of-type-any-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-ts/56745564?noredirect=1#comment100051156_56745564)) we've manually specified the generic parameter of the `reduce()` array to turn off the faulty inference of `[]` as an array of `never[]`.

Now it should work without complaint.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/?target=6#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-DVnW5gphMtIMOKPIfAAvAclxZqW+w2Ng3DTJgDHqGGABEvCcam8apgojHCGInDsbwXE8XxfFyJcABC7HWMxrFiRJvEpvxKaCaAwmiKJkaMeJoDcWpGnxsR6j3usDD1pMGAzHMCygAAYkpMy0cchk4dq9ZplYSgwiwcQcNYv4uSxMy2axDkcAA4iIunuRxMY4N55l+YEHCIEFNi-nFIkTFM9nzBwYWsXgWYSHlukEIcxyKeFbHOa5mA1vWxw6XpVWcK1xETFYdiYqIQLcB8eDxPA2DWB8pUzOVlXxa4FngpK8CGnYoh8Igv5ZfEbjmIOaqgDRpooD6aI2pAlGOsgZiENssB+jNmBzYQXV4MGlw2vM8AKBG-YKIOwKwPGzpUYGiUeatyD1axyCcKIeCsDayAo4DIIRjU8bQ81jptS233IB1cMI0jKPIGjsARnUWMdbjeKgGYDxPOoq145plyMTDMylvGCgdTzqbmHTQA)

Comment: the warning now `Object is of type 'unknown'.` come from `...value[0].filter` and `...value[1].group` :(

Comment: simple way i'm update my answer like this : `{filter: <any>[], group: <any>[]}` but the warning now `Object is of type 'unknown'.` and update this : `const body = request.body as const;` ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue... I've added a link to the code in my answer where you can see that there is no compiler error.  If you are still having problems there must be something in your environment or code you haven't posted here.  Please try to make sure your example code constitutes a [mcve] or it will be hard for anyone to help you.  Good luck!

Comment: If you enable `noUnusedParameters` you do get a warning about `key`, which can be fixed by `(acc, [, value]) => { ...`

Comment: just to add some advice, never cast in the accumulator like that; as an alternative pass through the generic manually to reduce prettier will format it better and it has stronger type saftey.